# Missing lib/logic.js file in a deployed network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

something weird has been happening to me, with the 0.20 version of the hyperledger composer framework, operating on a hlfv12 network. I have the following hyperledger composer project structure:

```
lib/logic.js
models/.cto file
queries.qry
package.json
permissions.acl
README.md
```

If I type in composer archive create -a demo@0.0.1.bna -t dir -n . all the files get included in the generated .bna file, in the exact same structure.

Buut, if I then install and deploy the network (no errors get raised btw), the logic.js file is missing! And, as a result I get Error: Could not find any functions to execute for transaction.

I checked the network with the playground web app, and I can confirm the js file is nowhere to be found. I can add it manually, for sure, and then the network works as intended. But it ain't so quick and easy to do over many iterations.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem myself, there must be something wrong with my node and/or hyperledger installation.
Everything works on a fresh ubuntu machine.